# How to associate an image with a term taxononmy and publish it on frontpage?

Tags: images, taxonomy, terms

I couldn't find the solution anywhere else, so I believe is a valid question for this website. I think my problem is divided in two parts. I created a custom taxonomy called "Type" and within it, I have terms (tags) like "cool", "sad", "amazing"..and so on.

1) I want to associate an icon for each one of my terms.
2) I want to display those icons (within link to the term archive) in my front page, like a feature image for each post.

No idea how to do that. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-categories-2/) plugin lets you categorize images, and in the latest update I've added to ability to pass a 'category' parameter to the standard gallery shortcode.

So perhaps you could use the gallery shortcode to present your images on your front page.

My next release will include the ability to filter the taxonomy that is being used so that its not tied to the category taxonomy specifically.

Comment: Because of this thread I think I should include in the next release a simple template function to which you could pass a category, and probably some arguments to fiddle with the query - that way developers wont need to bother with do_shortcode() to use it outside of post content.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - the code for that plugin (Taxonomy Images) only works where there's a category object (like on category.php) so it won't work on the front page.  To get it working there you can do some extra coding as @Hrvoje explains on this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40774/11711

Answer (score 0):

This plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/ and the documentation should give you what you need to get started.

It requires coding to use, but since you've already created a custom taxonomy, .....

Comment: Thanks. I know that plugin but I couldn't find the function that would let me post the images on my front page. Anyway, I'll check again.

Answer (score 0):

Or... another option would be to use [Taxonomy Images II](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-images-ii/other_notes/).  It works similar, but has some more intuitive template tags that can go anywhere.  The only catch is it outputs the html (as I understand) for the img tag, as opposed to just giving you the src (or title, alt, size, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Awesome Taxonomies plugin](https://wpxtre.me/product/awesome-taxonomies/).

With Awesome Taxonomies you can associate images to WordPress Taxonomies with ease; this plugin comes also with an extended category widget that support taxonomy images.

If you need any kind of help, you're welcome.

*Disclaimer: I'm the Ceo of wpXtreme.*